# Hibernation and Sleep mode not working as expected

Tags: suspend, shutdown, hibernate

Every time I try sleep mode computer won't partially shut down as expected, it just log out. Similar strange behaviour apply to hibernation mode when computer restarts instead of shutting down (yes, my computer is capable of hibernation). However, shutting down or logging out works fine. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with Xfce for several months already and I'm happy with it but this thing driving me crazy because back in windows I was using hibernation mode a lot and I'd like to keep this style of workflow.I wish to tell you more but I really don't know what is happening on background or what causing it. Although I didn't told you much, I told you everything I know about this problem.

Comment: Did you install Xubuntu 18.04? or Ubuntu 18.04 then added the XFCE desktop?   Hibernate is a much more difficult question (it's hardware specific), but sleep should work, so I'm wondering if you didn't install the full desktop & are missing something.  If you `sudo systemctl suspend` (*press enter, [entering password if asked, enter] then do nothing & it should suspend*) - does it?

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for digging in my problem. Suspending (sleeping) from terminal works as expected. I first installed Ubuntu 16 then added XFCE desktop and after some time updated to Ubuntu 18. I'm using Whisker menu so possibly, Whisker menu is calling wrong commands. I know my laptop is capable of hibernation but at end of process it restarts instead of shutting down... can it be wrong command too ?

Comment: My install is Ubuntu too, with `xubuntu-desktop` added, so I know I have everything. Long ago I used to add individual packages in hopes of getting a smaller footprint, but decided it took too much effort. I doubt it's a wrong command being issued, but still suspect it's a missing package that causes the command to not get executed. There is no `xfce-desktop` package, can you please look in logs (/var/log/apt/history* or /var/log/dpkg*) to see if you can find how you added XFCE.  Was it `xfce4`?  (https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/xfce4); ie. `egrep` your logs looking for xfce maybe..

Comment: fyi: the command to hibernate is `sudo systemctl hibernate` (if you hadn't guessed).   
 Just a thought - wonder if this package is causing your issue - https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/caffeine , you could check to see if it's installed, if it is, please `sudo apt install --reinstall caffeine` (*to ensure it's valid; a `purge` then `install` may be better, but if you use it for specific purposes, you'd lose whatever changes you made to its config..*)